# PHP Curl to get a download filesize

Tags: php, cookies, curl, filesize

I use this script in two different servers:

```
function curlGetFileInfo($url, $cookies="default"){
global $_config;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'serverpath/cookies/'.$cookies.'.txt');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
if ($data === false) { 
    return 0;
}
//echo $data;   
$info['filename'] = get_between($data, 'filename="', '"');
$info['extension'] = end(explode(".",$info['filename']));
if (preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches)) {
  $info['filesize'] = (int)$matches[1];
}
return $info;
}
```

These servers have the same PHP version with the same PHP-Curl version. These are the two different headers of the curl result:

**Working one:**

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 07:04:35 GMT Server:
>   Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze13 Expires:
>   Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store,
>   no-cache,must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache
>   Location:
>   http://stor1076.uploaded.to/dl/b3411ded-0f45-4efc-b705-8c8ac89b5e41
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding Connection: close Content-Type: text/html
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.0.5 Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 07:04:35
>   GMT Content-Type: video/x-msvideo Content-Length: 733919232
>   Last-Modified: Tue, 29 May 2012 15:10:07 GMT Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename="Saw.[Spanish.DVDRip].[XviD-Mp3].by.SDG.avi" Accept-Ranges:
>   bytes

**Non working one:**

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 07:05:26 GMT Server:
>   Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze13 Expires:
>   Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,
>   must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Location:
>   http://stor1164.uploaded.to/dl/22c3d242-365d-4e1e-b903-f1e2b81812c2
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding Connection: close Content-Type: text/html

Cookies are set OK (with login), and other simple Curl functions are working fine.

Also, I did a `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)` and give me that result:

**Working one:**
200

**Non working one:**
302

Any idea?

Comment: Ok, it was a open_basedir problem. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was a open_basedir problem. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

On the working one you seem to be running Apache as well as **nginx**. You can see there are two HTTP responses:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 07:04:35 GMT Server:
>   Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.0.5

So, your setup differs. I don't know how exactly they are running together, but this gives some insight and may help you solve it: http://kbeezie.com/view/apache-with-nginx/

Comment: They are not "running together", The first request is just redirected.

Comment: Ok, it was a open_basedir problem. Thanks anyway mate!

Comment: I meant 'running together' in terms of server configuration. But the problem was a different one anyway.